# Splitting Large Strings in Excel an Arbitrary Number of Times

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Suppose I have a 50 character string and I want to split it in to arbitrary chunks.  For example I might want to split it into chunks of 4,5,3,8,2... and so on.  What's the easiest way to do this in Excel without using LEFT RIGHT or other individual functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your 50 character string in cell **A2** and put your field widths in **B1,C1,....**

Then in **B2** enter:

```
=LEFT(A2,B1)
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=MID($A$2,SUM($B$1:B1)+1,C1)
```

and copy **C2** across.  Here is an example:

[image]

*Just be sure that top row of field widths add up to **50***

While this solution does use individual string functions, it is completely driven by the field widths.

Comment: Why must they add up to 50? If you use `MID` with values higher than the string length, it just returns an empty string. I would say to make sure that they add up to *at least* the length of your string to make sure all text is captured. Alternatively, you could have the last cell use `LEN($A2)` as it's `num_chars` parameter so it catches whatever's left.

Comment: @EngineerToast Both of your suggestions are very good.